# Plot 2-d graph as a solution of system of equations

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

I have two functions $y=y(x)$ and $z=z(x,y)$ and I need to plot a graph for $y=y(z)$ but I can't express variable $x$ and substitute it in another function. So could you help me, how can I plot this graph in numerical way in Mathematica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
ParametricPlot[{y[x],z[x,y[x]]},{x,...}]
```